# .htaccess Rewrite Based on Existence of Path in URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, blogs, subdomain

Here's the scenario, I have a website that used to be a static HTML site and WordPress blog using a subdomain (http://blog.domain.com).

I recently combined everything into a single WordPress installation. To maintain old links I had to rewrite requests like "http://blog.domain.com/index.php/2010/10/16/post-name" to "http://domain.com/index.php/2010/10/16/post-name". My problem is that when trying to visit just "http://blog.domain.com", I get redirected to "http://domain.com" when I want it to go to "http://domain.com/index.php/blog".

So, if a user requests "http://blog.domain.com" (by itself, with or without slash), I want it to go to "http://domain.com/index.php/blog". If they request an old URL of "http://blog.domain.com/some-link-to-a-post", I want it to redirect to "http://domain.com/some-link-to-a-post". In other words, if it's a URL to an actual post, I just want to strip the "blog" subdomain. If it's the old link to the main blog page, I want to remove the "blog" subdomain and append "/index.php/blog"

**http://blog.domain.com/** -> *http://domain.com/index.php/blog*

**http://blog.domain.com/index.php/2010/10/16/post-title** -> *http://domain.com/index.php/2010/10/16/post-title*

Hopefully that's clear. I'm not an htaccess expert, so hopefully someone can help me out here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Using the `[L]` command at the end of a rewrite will tell htaccess that this is the last rule it should match. If you put a rule to match your first condition at the top and the other rewrite rule you said you had already created after it, you should get your expected result.

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^blog.domain.com(/?)$ domain.com/index.php/blog [L]
# Your other rewrite here #
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get that solution to work. However, I used the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/index.php/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

That ends up in a URL like http://domain.com/index.php/blog/index.php/2010/06/04/post-title, but Wordpress is smart enough to fix it.